# Need help regarding AWS SES SMTP service not available in the region

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, devops

[AWS SES Documentations page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u7vg.png)
I am trying to use aws ses for the smtp service in my application but when I checked the aws documentation it says "SMTP endpoints are not currently available in Israel (Tel Aviv)" but I have my hosting servers in Israel(Tel Aviv) region. so what should I do to configure AWS SES service to send SMTP mails.

can I configure smtp in another region and use its credentials to send mails from the application which is hosted in the Israel region.

I tried to setup this in another region but failed to find any significant guides.

Answer (score 0):

> "can I configure smtp in another region and use its credentials to
> send mails from the application which is hosted in the Israel region."

Yes, that's exactly what you need to do. First create the SMTP credentials in IAM. The IAM service is global (not region specific) so doing that once will work, regardless of what region you end up using SES in.

Next, configure SES in the region you want to use.

Finally, configure your application to use the IAM SMTP credentials you created, and to use the [SMTP endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/ses.html) (2nd table on that page) for the region you configured SES in.